# CRUD Opertaions with SQL Server CE database on device with Windows CE 5

Tags: c#, exception, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

There are a smart device, OS of this device is Windows CE 5. I want to write a c# smart device application program that running on this device. C# program must communicate with a SQL Server CE database.

`cedb1.sdf` is a SQL Server CE database that are creating on device when program will be run, I call below method on FormLoad():

```
public void InitializeDatabase()
{
    string startupPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
    string datalogicFilePath = Path.Combine(startupPath, "cedb1.sdf");

    SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(ConnectionString);

    if(!File.Exists(datalogicFilePath))
        engine.CreateDatabase();
    string query = "create table PersonelType(Id int primary key identity not null,Caption nvarchar(100) null)";
        ExecuteNonQuery(query);

    query = "create table Personel(Id int primary key identity not null,PersonelTypeId int not null,FirstName nvarchar(100) not null,LastName nvarchar(100) not null,CardNumber nvarchar(100) null)";
        ExecuteNonQuery(query);

    query = @"ALTER TABLE Personel
                ADD CONSTRAINT MyConstraint FOREIGN KEY (PersonelTypeId) REFERENCES
                PersonelType(Id)
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                on delete cascade";
    ExecuteNonQuery(query);
}
```

Database is successfully created.

Then on `FormLoad()` I call `RefreshGrid()` method to show all `PersonelTypes` in data grid:

```
private void RefreshGrid()
{
    PersonelTypeBLL personelTypeManager = new PersonelTypeBLL();
    dgPersonelTypes.DataSource = personelTypeManager.GetAll();
}
```

`PersonelType` is a businness object class:

```
public class PersonelType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

`RefreshGrid()` method calls `GetAll()` method in BLL :

```
public List<PersonelType> GetAll()
{
    var repository = new PersonelTypeDAL();
    var data = repository.GetAll();
    List<PersonelType> personelTypes = new List<PersonelType>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        PersonelType personelType = new PersonelType();
        personelType.Id = Convert.ToInt32(data.Rows[i]["Id"]);
        personelType.Caption = data.Rows[i]["Caption"].ToString();
        personelTypes.Add(personelType);
    }
    return personelTypes;
}
```

and corresponding method of `GetAll()` in BLL is `GetAll()` in DAL:

```
public DataTable GetAll()
{
    string query = "select id, caption from personeltype";
    return ExecuteDataTable(query);
}
```

the `ExecuteDataTable` method implemented in this way:

```
protected DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string commandText)
{
    using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = commandText;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        return dt;
    }
}
```

`ConnectionString` property is:

```
protected string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        string startupPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        string datalogicFilePath = Path.Combine(startupPath, "cedb1.sdf");
        return string.Format("DataSource={0};password=123456", datalogicFilePath);
    }
}
```

An exception occurred, message of exception is:

> Error, a native exception has occurred in SDPOffDbPersonel.exe

an in details of this exception write:

> ExceptionCode: 0xc0000005
>   ExceptionAddress: 0x01ca4008
>   Reading: 0x00650094
>   Faulting Mode: sqlceme35.dll
>   offset: 0x00004008
>
> at NativeMethods.GetKeyInfo(IntPtr pTx, String pwszBaseTable, IntPtr PrgDbKeyInfo, Int32 cDbKeyInfo, IntPtr pError) at SqlCeDataReader.FillMetaData(SqlCeCommand command)
>   at SqlCeCommand.InitializeDataReader(SqlCeDataReader reader, Int32 resultType)
>   at SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
>   at SqlCeCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
>   at DALBase.ExecuteDataTable(String commandText)
>   at PersonelTypeDAL.GetAll()
>   at PersonelTypeBLL.GetAll()
>   at Form1.RefreshGrid()
>   at Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   at Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>   at Form._SetVisibleNotify(Boolean fVis)
>   at Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
>   at Application.Run(Form frm)
>   at Program.Main()

What is problem? And how can I solve it?

regards

Comment: Have you checked if the value returned by ExecutingAssembly .... is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is an issue with version mismatch between the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll file and the unmanaged dll files on the device - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/fd60ba69-e4d6-441a-901f-947ac7a46d3c/ - solution is to make sure same version is used in dev environment and device, perferably SSCE 3.5 SP2 - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8831

Comment: thank you, i am using SSCE 3.5 SP1, and for developing i use VS 2008, and i download SSCE 3.5 SP2 from above link and still the problem is in his place.

Comment: And you do not include System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll with your project?

Comment: I Reference to this assembly, and copy it to device beside running application file

Comment: I think you should not copy it

Comment: The problem is solved, i download and install SSCE 3.5 SP1 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17020, and SP2 dont supported by device. thank you very much

Comment: 3.5 SP2 IS supported by device - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8831